# How to delete space and characters in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question about Excel, I want to do two things :

> - Delete spaces ' ' which are before of elements from one column
> - Delete spaces ' ' and all characters which are not digits from one column.

Is it possible to do that and how?

Examples:
I have theses data :

```
Exp question 1 :  
 excel
 sun 
 Microsystem ....

My result that I know : 
excel
sun
Microsystem ....

Exp question 2 :
Tel: 08 89 98 34 84 

My result that I know : 
0889983484
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your first data is in column A, starting row 1, the following formula will do that. Copy down, then copy / paste values over your starting data to replace it.

```
=MID(A1,FIND(TRIM(A1),A1),LEN(A1))
```

Assuming your second set of data is in column B, use this second formula to remove all spaces:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1," ","")
```

Comment: Thank you  :-) I think that the first sentence is difficult to understand for me :P